# How to make my html table responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

i have created a html table wchich is similar to 2d structure.i want to make that table responsive.i have tried some methods already. column responsive method is not suitable for my table because it is becoming difficult to understand the table data.any other suggestions??

my example table structure is similar to this

```html
<table class="indoor-table" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #e67817;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid #e67817; text-align: center;">pixel pitch</th>
<th style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817; text-align: center;" align="center">3</th>
<th style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817; text-align: center;" align="center">4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 20%; border: 1px solid #e67817;">Module Resolution (W*H Pixel)</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">192*192</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">128*128</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">160*160</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">160*160</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">192*96</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" colspan="2" align="center">32*16</td>
<td style="width: 11.5%; border: 1px solid #e67817;" align="center">16*16</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

some responsive methods are not working properly because of colspan,i don't want to use horizontal scroll method.so suggest me an alternative which suits my table.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but your question is simply too broad... please give examples of **exactly** what you mean, because at the moment I really have no idea.  [Please read the "how to ask a good question" in the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are several UI/UX techniques to make a table responsive : inverting it, hiding some columns, ... the one you choose depends on the needs and the data. Sometimes it might even be that you can't afford any of these techniques and your user will just need to scroll...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this blog post, it gives you some ideas and plugins that can be used:

http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns

There isn't an accepted method for doing responsive tables. If there is too much data or the data in the table contains a lot of characters it is very difficult.

A lot of people are using an adaptive approach where the table view is completely different for mobile.

Without seeing your table it is difficult to propose a suitable solution to you but I think you should be able to find something in that blog post which will fit your needs.